# Angular Material Radio buttons - default selection

Tags: angular-material

I want to set a default selection for a `radio group`

In my `html` file I have

```
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedId">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="-1" [checked]="selectedId === -1"
            ><span i18n="@@keep-origin">Keep origin</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
        @for (info of data; track info.id) {
            <mat-radio-button [value]="info.id">{{ info.label }}</mat-radio-button>
        }
    </mat-radio-group>
        <pre>{{ selectedId }}</pre>
```

And in my `ts` file I have

```
export interface DataDto {
    label: string;
    id: string;
}
...
    selectedId = -1;
```

I would expect to have the first option selected - since it has the value `-1`. I would have expected that `checked` is not required since its handled via the `ngModel`. Additionally the `<pre>` Tag displays when I select the second option `info.id` instead of the value of the `id`.

Using Angular Material 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not have any issues, please check the below working example! please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated if the issue persists!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
export interface DataDto {
  label: string;
  id: string;
}
/**
 * @title Basic radios
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-overview-example',
  template: `
  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedId">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="-1"
      ><span i18n="@@keep-origin">Keep origin</span>
    </mat-radio-button>
    @for (info of data; track info.id) {
    <mat-radio-button [value]="info.id">{{ info.label }}</mat-radio-button>
    }
  </mat-radio-group>
  <pre>{{ selectedId }}</pre>

  `,
  styleUrl: 'radio-overview-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatRadioModule, FormsModule],
})
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  selectedId = -1;
  data: DataDto[] = [
    { id: '1', label: 'one' },
    { id: '2', label: 'two' },
    { id: '3', label: 'three' },
  ];
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dwtbtm?file=src%2Fexample%2Fradio-overview-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fradio-overview-example.html)

Comment: I restart my whole environment and now it works perfectly. Honestly don't know why it failed while developing/compiling :-/ Anyway the reassurance that it worx helped a lot! Thx